# Is a linear map between two vector spaces with dimension $n$ that maps a set whose cardinality is $n$ to a basis in range bijective?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

Let $f:V \to W$ be a linear map, where $V,W$ are finite-dimensional and $\dim V =\dim W = n$.

I know that if $f$ maps a basis of $V$ to a basis of $W$ then $f$ is bijective. But I wonder if $f$ maps a set $X \subseteq V$ whose cardinality is $n$ to a basis of $W$ implies $f$ is bijective.

This is my attempt:
Let $X =\{\vec{x}_1 \cdots,\vec{x}_n\} \subseteq V$. Suppose that $f(X) = \{f(\vec{x}_1) \cdots,f(\vec{x}_n)\}$ is a basis of $W$. To show $X$ is a basis, we need only to prove that $X$ is linearly independent. If it was not, then we could find two different group of scalars $a_i,b_i$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i\vec{x}_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n{b_i\vec{x}_i}
$$
, which would imply that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n{a_if(\vec{x}_i)} = \sum_{i=1}^n{b_if(\vec{x}_i)}
$$
, contradicting to the fact that $f(X)$ is a basis.

Therefore, $f$ maps a basis to a basis, and thus it is bijective.

Did I do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, but you can prove it directly. Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ satisfy a linear relation
$$
a_1x_1+ \cdots a_nx_n = 0.
$$
Then
$$
a_1f(x_1) + \cdots a_nf(x_n) = 0
$$
since $f$ is linear. Since $f(x_1),\ldots,f(x_n)$ is a basis, $a_1 = \cdots = a_n = 0$.